# Typescript conditional type depending of a boolean within the same Type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to make an attribute of a `Type` be `A` or `B` depending on a `boolean` of the same type. Something like this:

```
interface ICardsGridSection {
  title: string;
  isSmallCard?: boolean;
  data: ICardsGridSection['isSmallCard'] extends true ? ICard[] : IFullCard[];
}
```

This is to limit the type of data of the Cards' grid depending on which card is wanted to be rendered in the `react` component.

So if someone does

```
<CardsGrid isSmallCard data={[]}/>
```

`data` type would be `ICard[]`

But, if instead it's:

```
<CardsGrid data={[]}/>
```

`data` type would be `IFullCard[]`

Answer (score 2):

Got it!

You need to create both type for each case. A bit too manual but it works

```
type TCardsGridSectionBase = {
  title: string;
  className?: string;
};

type TSmallCardsGrid = {
  isSmallCard?: true;
  data: ICard[];
};

type TCardsGrid = {
  isSmallCard?: false;
  data: IFullCard[];
};

type TCardsGridSection = TCardsGridSectionBase & (TSmallCardsGrid | TCardsGrid);
```